# ADT error codes

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I am creating some APP in ADT and I am following one tutorial but I am stuck at performing button to change my text to seomething else. The problem is that, in the tutorial, he uses older version of ADT and mine is newer so it doesn't work anymore. The code what there is is like this:

(package name etc)

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
            final TextView textOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textik);
            Button pushthis = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gombik);}
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: App doent start at all, but I just  need some help how to change it.
I need to add action like when I click my button its change the text. something like : pushthis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       
       @Override
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        textOne.setText("Hovno");
       }
      })
        }
    }

Comment: If you look in the console or error tab in Eclipse it should tell you why it doesn't start.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a better example to follow.
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

The main think I see wrong with your code is

```
final TextView textOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textik);
Button pushthis = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gombik);
```

They should not be initalized and declared here. If your using fragments, you should move it to the fragments. Below is a simple example.

```
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment implements Button.OnClickListener{
    TextView textOne;
    Button pushthis;
        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            textOne = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textik);
            pushthis = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gombik);
            //set handlers and anything else
            pushthis.setOnClickListener(this);

            return rootView;
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.gombik:
                   textOne.setText("HI");
                   break;
            }
        }
    }
```